# X server in Ubuntu

Tags: unity

What is X-server software in Ubuntu, I want to install oracle 12c dbms software but before installing I need to start X-server software, can anybody tell any easier way to install the software.

Comment: X is your graphical environment, most likely you already have it running. Have you tried running your software yet? The chances are good it will just work without you touching X :)

Comment: actually i am installing it using oracle installation guide, so firstly it is suggesting to start the X-server software, I don't understand what it is & how do i start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly spoken an X Server is the software that displays all the GUI elements and takes your input (keyboard and mouse).

So if you have a graphical desktop you have an X Server running.

Comment: can you suggest me how do i install oracle 12c in my Ubuntu 14.04, the steps mentioned in installation guide is quite confusing.

Comment: @vikash I suggest you ask a new question about that.